# "Show Source of Selected Element Only" in Visual Studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio

There is a feature in Eclipse ("Show Source of Selected Element Only") which allows to view the code of the selected method only. All other part of the code is invisible.

I remember that a similar feature was available in Visual Studio 6.0. I would like to know if this feature is available in Visual Studio 2003 and up? If yes, please point out where to find this in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

This is not available in any one of the later releases. It was called "procedure view" in VS 6. Use outlining feature instead.